# Calculus - Shell method - volume of function below a line

Tags: calculus, integration

Use the Shell Method to find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating region above the graph of $f(x) = x^2+2$ and below $y = 18$ for $0 < x < 4$ about the $y$-axis.

This problem is really baffling me as I was able to correctly solve a problem that is almost identical, except for the "below $y = 18$" aspect.

I know the formula for this would be the integral from $a$ to $b$ of $2\pi(x - \text{length})\cdot f(x)$

however everything I've tried has come up short. any help would be amazing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MathematicsStudent1122's answer above uses the disk method about the y axis. The solution by shell method is

$$2\pi \int_{0}^{4}x(16-x^2) \, dx = 128\pi$$

$x$ here is the radius of the cylindrical shell (distance from axis of rotation), $18 - (x^2 + 2) = 16 - x^2$ is the height of the shell and $dx$ is the infinitesmal thickness.

Answer (score 0):

We simply compute $\pi \int_2^{18} (\sqrt{y-2})^2 \ dy = 128\pi$.

The "below $y=18$" simply gives an upper limit for the integral, since now we're working with $y$ as the variable.

Comment: Thanks so much, just for reference, was the formula you used the disk method or the shell method?

Comment: I apologize, I don't know what particular method this is. It's just the first thing that came to mind :P